# Viewing of the process of execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to see which part of your codes are currently being executed without stopping the flow?

Currently i have invoices to process in my webpage, usually it takes about 4-5 mins to get the job done, however recently it has been slowing down quite a bit, even though its the same amount of data load.

Is there a way to track and see the process of the program through the codes? 
currently what I'm doing is going through breakpoints to see the speed for each invoice, however its not really feasible as i have hundreds of them to go through.

Another way which I'm currently doing is constantly refreshing the database to see the new records coming in and their time taken to process.

Currently running Visual Studio Express 2013 for web. 
.net 4.0

Comment: Computers are pretty fast. What would you see if you could see anything?

Comment: Apparently its taking very long, i would be able to see at which line of code or method it's taking a long time to process.

Comment: If you are troubleshooting a performance issue suggest you use a tool like Redgate profiler rather than littering your code base with `StopWatch`'s and Logging

Comment: Visual studio has a built in profiler, start with that:
Analyze->Profiler->Attach/Detach to attach to your running process

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, managed to find the problem with the codes, one of the if else branch was not updated correctly that caused the lag. What i did that worked was to put breakpoints in-between crucial method calls. And practically held the F5 key till it reached one invoice that was massively slow. This way it did give me some visual feedback of where the program was going, a quick fix for me, but i believe not the best way to solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Litter your code with logging calls.

Put it into a method that you call.. but mark it with the `Conditional` attribute so that the calls are optimized out of a Release build:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")] // calls are optimized away
public static void Log(string message) {
    // implement logging logic here
}
```

Comment: But note that if you add a lot of logging, you'll need to read a lot of logging.

Comment: So in other words ill be logging them into a text file, Which i will need to constantly refresh to see the current process.

Comment: Yes, and you'll need to actually _read_ that text file to find out what's been going on. It's a case of "be careful what you wish for".

Comment: Ok cool, probably ill add the time at the first line of the code and at the last line of it to see it's duration for each item. Actually this might just do the job. THANKS!

Comment: Back to 1982 PRINT "START"